# How shall i dynamically add node to tree for n-order tree?

Tags: php, algorithm, data-structures, tree, data-mining

I am trying to implement a similar algorithm to Fp growth that will be generating frequent itemsets.. but I am not sure about how shall I implement; how sall i dynamically add node to the tree on dataset traversal through each transaction... I am uploading an image that demonstrates structure of tree I need to create for given input..
[image: Click this to view Tree format as per input]

Answer (score 0):

Use a **list** to store the children, not fields.

Lists are good for dynamic length data.